# Any API to list out email id of a user's facebook friends?

Tags: facebook, email

Is there anyway to list out the email address, name of facebook friends of a user? Is any API available?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Facebook will only let you access the email address of a user who has authenticated your app. You cannot, therefore, access the email addresses of your users' friends.

You can retrieve a list of Facebook users' friends by processing the data returned from the following URL:

https://graph.facebook.com/USER_ID/friends?access_token=YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN

Where:

- USER_ID is the Facebook ID of that user
- ACCESS_TOKEN is a token granted by Facebook to your app after a the user authorizes it. [Facebook Authentication Docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/)

For more details, see the Graph API Docs:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/